# Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Tags: java, jenkins

I've configured my project to run the Build with Jenkins if I execute the testng.xml on my own it successfully execute my test case but if I execute via Jenkins I get the following error message

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

However it execute the build successfully if test case output is just using `(system.out.println();)

if test case relates to opening of browsers it gets failed via Jenkins

This is my test class

```
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseUrl = "http://iparkit.com/";

    @BeforeMethod
      public void initializeWebDriver() {

          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.get(baseUrl);
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
      }
    //Close Browser after each test case execution
    @AfterMethod
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
    @Test(enabled=true) //TC2-01 - OK
    public void iparkit_valid_email_password() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mast']/nav/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("imanltd+1@hotmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("*******");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='top']/div/main/form/main/fieldset[3]/button")).click();
        String Expectedlnktext = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).getText();
        String Actuallnktext = "Sign Out";
        Assert.assertEquals(Actuallnktext,Expectedlnktext);
    }
}
```

and here is my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="automationframework.Iparkittesting"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

here is last console output

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace D:\K - Selenium\SeleniumWorkspace\iParkit_copy
[iParkit_copy] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson4187523140058494240.bat

D:\K - Selenium\SeleniumWorkspace\iParkit_copy>run.bat

D:\K - Selenium\SeleniumWorkspace\iParkit_copy>java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 
[TestNG] Running:
  D:\K - Selenium\SeleniumWorkspace\iParkit_copy\testng.xml


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: anyone can solve this issue of mine????

Comment: Please set path correctly then it work fine 
Open CMD
set classpath=C:\Users\Learn-automation\bin;C:\Users\Learn-automation\libs\*;

then run below command if it is working fine from cmd then it will work

java -cp bin;libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: Well I am able to run the test suite via command prompt but same Failure getting using Jenkins let me tell you one more thing about the hierarchy of my project 
1: D:\K - Selenium\SeleniumWorkspace\iParkit_copy\bin\automationframework 

there is a package folder after bin , should it be included while setting classpath or any other plugin required to run it successfully, can we have screenshare session for sometime so that you may look into the problem by yourself, I am sending you my skype via email.
Thanks

Comment: One more thing to add I observed whenever it comes to the step where (sendKeys) involved build failed using Jenkins please advice

Comment: this is also ur question which is same.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536895/jenkins-build-failing-for-a-test-case-when-it-have-sendkeys-function?noredirect=1#comment56858095_34536895]
but you provide detail error log here.
Use this code:



public WebDriver driver = null;
you can try this but not sure this will solve ur problem or not.

Answer (score 7):

Using `exit /b 0` at the end of the batch script should do the trick.

Comment: This answer is great, but it would be a lot more helpful if you could also explain what the command means.

Answer (score 0):

The batch command will examine the "error level" of the last command (return code).
Anything but zero will result in failure.
You don't give much details, but it seems your browser returns a non-zero error level.

You could run a dummy command after the browser to chance the error level. Or fix whatever reason is causing the non-zero error level (recommended solution)

Example of a popular dummy command to set the error level is "ver > nul"

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: The answer should be elaborated some more. What is meant by dummy command? How to do that? Any example of what can cause non-zero error level.

Comment: "ver > nul" is a popular dummy command. The "error level" return code is completely application specific, so it is not possible to give any general examples of what can cause a non-zero errorlevel. You have to check the documentation of the application in question.