# Jenkins build failing for a test case when it have SendKeys() function

Tags: selenium, jenkins

If I run my test suite (Selenium WebDriver) with test cases giving text output only using

```
System.out.println("some text");
```

Build status is successful using Jenkins. But whenever it comes to the step where (sendKeys) involved build gets failed status with following message

> Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

e.g step

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("test");
```

Do I need to use headless browser or any plug-in to achieve success?

Following are the contents of run.bat

```
java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: without jenkins, ur test case pass or not?

Comment: yes it get passed let me paste the run.bat content in main thread for your review

Comment: I think your batch file is not working properly. First run your batch file through command line, i mean, not from jenkins. If not, you can go through this link to run a batch file in jenkins:

    [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e8I3A49ERc]

To run a simple batch file, no plugin is required.

Comment: I've executed the batch file via command line without jenkins and it worked perfectly